# What am I doing wrong with the creation of a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: plsql

Please create a PL/SQL procedure to print out names and grade of students taking a given class in a given year and semester. The input parameters are the class name, year, and semester. There is no output parameter.

My answer below is wrong:

```
Select s.sname
From Student s
Inner join grades g on g.sid= s.sid and g.cid = 1
    Inner join class c on c.semester='fall' AND year=2015 and c.cid=1;
```

Comment: Maybe you have not studied hard enough ? Please consult your lecture notes.

Comment: The absence of the phrase `create procedure` in your solution is a big clue.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not a pl/sql procedure. It is just a select statement. You need to create the pl/sql procedure with the syntax documented in the oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_procedure.htm